# What is the meaning of the word ‘gracile’?

Tags: terminology, interpretation

I am currently in the process of learning a piece that my piano teacher composed. 
As a bit of homework, in addition to deciphering the first page of music, he asked me to find out the meaning of the word ‘***gracile***’ (which is printed at the top of the sheet music, as seen in the picture attached.)
I have been searching all over google and through piano theory sites and dictionaries and I’m not sure if I’ve just been looking in the wrong places, but I can’t seem to find the definition! 
So here is my question; does anyone know/would anyone be able to tell me what the definition of ‘***gracile***’ is?
I would really appreciate an answer. Thank you :)[image]

Comment: Could be a translation of the French 'gracieux' - graceful.

Comment: *Gracile* is an anthropological term meaning slender &/or delicate. It's the opposite of *robust*. Presumably, but with nothing more than a bit of an extrapolation, I'd guess play it 'delicately'

Comment: Usually instructions in music are in Italian.  In Italian gracile means weak or puny but I guess delicate might just about fit.  Perhaps not the best choice of word to describe what is wanted though.

Answer (score 1):

Several words that could convey playing in a 'gracile' manner are - graciously, subdued, daintily, subtly, purely, sensitively, tastefully, lightly, and tenderly. Playing in just about any of these ways will produce the tone and feel needed.